# How to send AJAX with dataType as script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

im trying to create own POST request. Here is my function:

```
function sendPost(o) {
    var h = new XMLHttpRequest();
    h.onreadystatechange = requestComplete;

    function requestComplete() {
        if ( h.readyState === 4 ) {
            if ( h.status === 200 ) {
                if ( o.done ) {
                    o.done(h.responseText);
                }
            } else {
                if ( o.fail ) {
                    o.fail(h.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    h.open('POST', o.url, true);
    h.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    h.send(o.data);
}
```

Everything is OK, but im confused, how to set its dataType to **script**, like in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'script' // <-- how to do this?
});
```

Comment: what's wrong with jquery's ajax implementation?

Comment: It comes with the overhead of jQuery

Comment: nothing wrong with jQuery... im just forgotting `eval();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataType` has very little to do with *sending* Ajax requests. It is primarily about what jQuery does with the *response*.

From the documentation:

> "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.

So there is *some* modification to do with sending here.

1. Take `o.data`
2. Get a timestamp from a `new Date()`
3. Check (by looking at `indexOf('?')` if it has a query string already
4. Append either `?` or `&` to the URL followed by the time stamp

The rest is all about processing the response:

> Evaluates the response as JavaScript

So:

```
eval(h.responseText);
```

---

This is all rather nasty though. Generally speaking, if you want to dynamically load a script, you are usually better off doing it by adding a `<script>` element to a page.

Comment: Wow, great answer... thank you very much! This is helpful! i use the method of `eval(h.responseText);`